# Masking sensitive logs using regex

Tags: java, regex, logging, logback

I am trying to mask the logs by chaining replace regex in logback.xml file.

```
%replace(%replace(%msg){'"email":(.*?),','"email":"****"'}){'"phone":(.*?),','"phone":"****"'}))
```

It's working, but is there any other regex solution instead of regex replace chaining?

Can we use regex something like this?

```
(%replace(%msg){'"(email|phone)":(:*?)','"***",'}
```

I tried the above but the format is not proper.

Required output is:

```
{"email":"****","phone":"****"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(%replace(%msg){'"(email|phone)":[^,]*,?','"$1":"****"'})
```

The `"(email|phone)":[^,]*,?` regex matches

- `"` - a `"` char
- `(email|phone)` - Group 1 (`$1`): `email` or `phone` string
- `":`  -  a `":` string
- `[^,]*` - zero or more chars other than a comma
- `,?` - an optional `,` char.

The replacement is `"$1":"****"`: `"` + Group 1 value + `":"***"`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJjwOX/1).